# "I have been graduated from XYZ University in ABC-MSc" is correct?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, transitivity

**graduate** verb is intransitive and as far as I know, this sort of verbs couldn't be used as a passive form. Am I right?

I have strangely seen it is correct in some website like this:

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090717174145AACv5YR

Comment: It's one of those usage things. *To graduate* means to complete a degree. Say "I graduated from XYZ University." Don't get your grammar answers from yahoo.

Comment: The primary meaning of **graduate** is 'complete one's studies' but, according to online dictionaries, in _American_ usage you can speak of a university graduating its students.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not correct. If you “have been Xed” then someone else is doing the X and you are the recipient. For example, *I have been released from my obligation*. But completing a degree is something that you do yourself, so the phrase is

> I graduated University XYZ with a degree in ABC

Of course, since the University is doing the awarding, you could say

> I have been awarded a degree in ABC by the University XYZ